# How to capture Hide key event in Qt VirtualKeyboard

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am using Qt virtual Keypad in my project.

I am able to print key values (using event.key) in console log for all keys, except hide key event (which is marked as red color in attached image).

Can anyone please help me in capturing the hide key event in virtual keyboard.

Below is the sample code for capturing key events

```
TextField{
    id:sampletextfield
    width: window.width/1.5
    height: parent.height*.5
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    font.bold: true
    font.pixelSize: parent.height*.2

    Keys.onReleased: {
        console.log("key event = " + event.key)
    }
}
```

Virtual Keyboard

[image]

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Why do you want to capture when that button is pressed?

Comment: Hi,
Based on Hide key event, I want to popup a message

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm looking for an answer to the original question. I'd like to be able to switch from the virtual keyboard to an external keyboard or vice versa depending on a button click. I'd like to get the hidekeyboardkey clicked event to handle it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect when the virtualkeyboard is hidden then you can use [`Qt.inputMethod`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#inputMethod-prop):

```
Connections{
    target: Qt.inputMethod
    function onVisibleChanged(){
        if(Qt.inputMethod.visible){
           console.log("show")
        }
        else{
            console.log("hide")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you eyllanesc. This resolves my issue